# How to compute the number of likes and neutrals inside a single row in my database?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

How to display a number value for each Like from a single row in a database?

For example:

The image from the database would give a result in a page in php which can 
give a number value from every like and neutral in the database row

```
Like = 1 Neutral = 2
```

Comment: What is the structure of the database? Do you want to do the computation in PHP or SQL?

Comment: I see 1 Like and 2 Neutral... am I wrong? Also, please post your table as well formatted text instead of images

Comment: Obviously you can write a large `SELECT CASE WHEN ThisField = 'Like' then 1 else 0 end + CASE WHEN ThatField = 'Like' then 1 else 0 end + ... as 'Likes'` and likewise for Neutrals. But this table structure is so, well, non-relational, you cannot hope to go far with such a design :-)

Comment: The basic problem you've got here is that your table design is not normalised. If you have an "answers" table with fields like "questionID", "Answer", UserID" and associate it back to the user table, then the problem is trivial to solve with SQL - you can just use aggregate functions to count up the number of instances of each value.

Comment: Your table design really needs looking at. a single row to do what you are doing is inefficient. Typically, it is faster to query many short rows than few long rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, redesign your table. I'll do this one for you, but for future endevours you should really look up [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Rather than have a single row for each user response, instead have a single row for each answer, with an ID attached to identify who it belongs to (You haven't shown this in your sample, but I will assume this does exist somewhere in your row).

```
+----+------+------------+------------------+
| Id | User | QuestionID | QuestionResponse |
+----+------+------------+------------------+
|  1 |   45 |          1 | Like             |
|  2 |   45 |          2 | Neutral          |
|  3 |   45 |          3 | Like             |
|  4 |   46 |          1 | Dislike          |
|  5 |   46 |          2 | Dislike          |
+----+------+------------+------------------+
```

With a structure like this, you can perform counts far more easily

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(QuestionResponse) FROM QuestionTable WHERE QuetstionResponse = 'Like'
```

If you need a specific user, add `AND UserID = 46` to the end.

Now this table uses normalisation - user details are stored in another table because data duplication is baaaaad. You don't want or need to add personal details in each of these rows because it exists elsewhere already. We can access that data via a join. Assume the user table looks like this:

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| Id | Username | FirstName | LastName |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| 45 | Fbloggs  | Fred      | Bloggs   |
| 46 | Charray  | Charlotte | Harray   |
| 47 | Tmoseby  | Ted       | Moseby   |
| 48 | Dknute   | Deunan    | Knute    |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

you can access the user information via a join.

```
SELECT Users.Username, Count(QuestionResponse) FROM table
INNER JOIN Users ON QuestionTable.User = Users.Id
WHERE QuestionResponse = 'Like'
```

This would output

```
+----------+-------+
| Username | Count |
+----------+-------+
| Fbloggs  |     2 |
+----------+-------+
```